# Leaflet: Layer check box state is reset every time the map moves or zooms

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have the following code which fetches some remote GeoJSON from an API and displays the results on a Leaflet map:

```
<script>

    // Center the map
    var map = L.map('map').setView([54.233669, -4.406027], 6);


    // Attribution
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=REMOVED', {
        attribution: 'Map &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);


    // Create an empty layergroup for the data
    var LayerUTMGroundHazards = L.layerGroup();
    var LayerUTMAirspace = L.layerGroup();


    // Style the features
    function setStyle(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: feature.properties.fillColor,
            color: feature.properties.strokeColor,
            fillOpacity: feature.properties.fillOpacity,
            opacity: feature.properties.strokeOpacity
        };
    }


    // Build Guardian UTM
    function getGuardianUTMdata() {


        // Clear the current Layer content
        LayerUTMGroundHazards.clearLayers();
        LayerUTMAirspace.clearLayers();


        // Define what we want to include
        function FuncGroundHazards(feature) {
            if (feature.properties.category === "groundHazard") return true
        }
        function FuncAirspace(feature) {
            if (
                (feature.properties.category === "airspace" || feature.properties.category === "airport")
                && feature.properties.detailedCategory !== "uk:frz"
                ) return true
        }



        // Build the layers
        fetch("https://example.com/json?n=" + map.getBounds().getNorth() + "&e=" + map.getBounds().getEast() + "&s=" + map.getBounds().getSouth() + "&w=" + map.getBounds().getWest(), { headers: { 'Authorization': 'REMOVED', 'X-AA-DeviceId': 'mySite' } })
          .then(function (responseGuardianUTM) { return responseGuardianUTM.json() })
          .then(function (dataGuardianUTM) {

              // Create Layer: Ground Hazards
              var featuresUTMGroundHazards = L.geoJson(dataGuardianUTM, {
                  filter: FuncGroundHazards,
                  style: setStyle,
                  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) { return L.marker(latlng, { icon: L.icon({ iconUrl: feature.properties.iconUrl, iconSize: [25, 25], }), }) },
                  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name); },
              });
              // Add the L.GeoJSON instance to the empty layergroup
              LayerUTMGroundHazards.addLayer(featuresUTMGroundHazards).addTo(map);

          });


          // other layers are here (removed from this example)

    }



    // Update the Guardian UTM layer if the map moves
    map.on('dragend', function () { getGuardianUTMdata(); });
    map.on('zoomend', function () { getGuardianUTMdata(); });


    // Layer controls
    var layerControl = new L.Control.Layers(null, {
        'Airspace Restrictions': LayerUTMAirspace,
        'Ground Hazards': LayerUTMGroundHazards
        // other layers are here (removed from this example)
    }).addTo(map);


</script>
```

The problem is that every time the map is moved or zoomed, all of the Layer checkboxes are reset to Checked again, regardless of how many *were* checked before the map moved. They do not honour / remember their state when the map moves.

Given my code above, how can I store or preserve the checkbox state for each of the multiple Layers that I have so they are not reset every time the map is moved?

EDIT:
Here is a working fiddle.  Remove the checkbox from the 'Ground Hazards', then move or zoom the map, you will see how it puts a tick back in the box again

https://jsfiddle.net/hdwz1b6t/1/

Comment: On the face of it your code looks ok, no reason it should reset the state of the layerGroups within the Layers Control. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, I don't know if I can create a fiddle without revealing API keys and domain names. Unless there's a public geojson example somewhere that I could use?

Comment: Maybe you can snag a representative chunk of data and load it statically in the fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the support, I've just added a working fiddle to demonstrate this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're (re-)adding `LayerUTMGroundHazards` every time. This line here...

```
      // Add the L.GeoJSON instance to the empty layergroup
      LayerUTMGroundHazards.addLayer(featuresUTMGroundHazards).addTo(map);
```

...is not only adding `featureUTMGroundHazards` to `layerUTMGroundHazards`, it's **also** (re-)adding `layerUTMGroundHazards` to the `map`.

And quoting from https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/ :

> The layers control is smart enough to detect what layers we’ve already added and have corresponding checkboxes and radioboxes set.

So when you do `LayerUTMGroundHazards.addTo(map);`, the checkboxes reset.

Comment: I see!  So by replacing `LayerUTMGroundHazards.addLayer(featuresUTMGroundHazards).addTo(map);` with `LayerUTMGroundHazards.addLayer(featuresUTMGroundHazards);` the issue is resolved!  Thanks for the help Ivan!  (again!)